# Command \ch and \arctg already defined

Tags: document-classes

Two errors:
document.tex: error: 2: Command \ch already defined. \begin{document}
document.tex: error: 2: Command \arctg already defined. \begin{document}
for that simple piece of code:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{jetpl}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

JETPL class file is from here: http://jetpletters.ru/tex/utf8/jetpl.cls

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

The class will always give those errors. It loads `babel` with the `russian` option and `russianb.ldf` will then be loaded which does, amongst other things

```
    \DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{ch}%\MakeRobust\ch
    \DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}%\MakeRobust\tg
    \DeclareMathOperator{\ctg}{ctg}%\MakeRobust\ctg
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}%\MakeRobust\arctg%
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arcctg}{arcctg}%\MakeRobust\arcctg%
```

but the class itself also does

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ch}{\myglue\hbox{--}\hskip.167em}
```

and

```
\def\arctg{\mathop{\text{arctg}}\nolimits}
```

You should report this to the class maintainers but the simplest fix is to comment the lines out of the class file (lines 571 and 1241)

Comment: “[...] let not thy left hand know what thy right hand doeth.”